# BufferedWriter do not write to a file

Tags: java, file, bufferedwriter

I am trying to make a text editor, but I am unable to save the contents to a text file : the file is created but empty.

```
class Saver implements ActionListener{
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

            try{
        File file = new File("projekat");
        if(!file.exists()){
        file.createNewFile();   

        FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        bw.write(tekst1);
        bw.close();
        }
            }
            catch(IOException ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
    }

}
```

JTextArea code

```
    area = new JTextArea(tekst1, 30,30);
    tekst1 = area.getText();
```

Please help me. Best regards

Comment: `tekst1` is empty String.

Comment: @Djehenghizz Now that the tekst1 is empty, all things that write to the file is empty. So it is normal. Huh?

Comment: Are you aware that writing to the file only happens if the file didn't exist before (check the if clause `!file.exists()`)? That means that if the program is executed and the file already exists nothing is written. You could check if that is the problem by first deleting the file and then running the program.

Comment: This must be a joke.... isn't it ?

Comment: @Tobold I've already tried that, but it is same.

Comment: What do you expect to be written to the file if  `tekst1` is empty?

Comment: @Djehenghizz And what about writing a non-empty string in your file ?

Comment: @Dici writing non-empty string in file is working. I am getting `tekst1` from JTextArea, and I think that is problem..

Comment: So the problem is not writing to a file but getting the text from a JTextArea. If you post the relevant code we might be able to help.

Comment: Can you please post a complete piece of code by editing your question?

Comment: The problem is probably that you need to call `tekst1 = area.getText();` again in your `actionPerformed` method to update the contents of `tekst1`. It is hard to tell though because the code you posted obviously isn't complete.

Comment: @Tobold thats is, it is working. I should call `tekst1 = area.getText();` again. Thanks a lot !

Comment: Glad to hear. I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you need to call `tekst1 = area.getText();` 
again in your `actionPerformed` method to update the contents of `tekst1`.

```
class Saver implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        try {
            File file = new File("projekat");
            if (!file.exists()) {
                file.createNewFile();

                FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
                BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);

                // get latest contents of the JTextArea
                tekst1 = area.getText();

                bw.write(tekst1);
                bw.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

bw.write(tekst1);
this line writes the content to the file.
you were close, the string you are writing is just empty, so it's normal that nothing writes to the file.

Some examples:
http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-bufferedwriter-example/
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/bufferedwriter_write_string.htm
http://beginnersbook.com/2014/01/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-using-bufferedwriter/

Comment: But I should `getText()` from JTextArea, shouldn't I ?

Answer (score 0):

include only this code :---
   file.createNewFile(); 
  in your if statement and place other things out of your if.

Comment: File is created in project folder, so I think there is no need to set path.

Comment: sry i didnt checkd the created file... try this ans.